# Excel - Pull cell contents from columns into rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got a table such as this:

[image]
And I have another worksheet with the data transposed, such as this:

[image: Transposed Table]

I want the **transposed sheet** to update whenever I update the **original sheet**.

I've tried to add another line beneath the transposed table, at line 4,
and pulling all the appropriate names:

**Cell A (Transposed)** <- **Cell B (Original)** (the <- means pull the contents of Cell B into Cell A).

A4 <- Sheet1!D1

B4 <- Sheet1!D2

C4 <- Sheet1!D3

D4 <- Sheet1!D4

The problem is, when I try to autocomplete the next line using the little plus (+) mark at the bottom of my selection, lo and behold what happens:

[image]

It makes cell A5, which **should** pull from cell Sheet1!E1, pull from cell Sheet1!D2 instead!

How do I auto-complete this correctly, without writing every single cell myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a formula simply transposing content of another sheet you can use this:

`=OFFSET('Another Sheet'!A1,COLUMN()-1,ROW()-1)`
(copy this in cell A1)

or this one:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN(),ROW(),1,1,"Another sheet"))`

After entering these formula you can just drag them to any direction and will work.

[image]

Of course, you can also use `TRANSPOSE` as suggested already, but there is more difficult to modify it.

Comment: This is actually better than `TRANSPOSE()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Select blank cells

First select target blank cells. But make sure to select the target number of cells you want to add items transposed later. For example, there are 3 columns in your sheet1, but as the item number grows, the target cells number should increase. Because this is an array formula, the target cells should be pre-selected.

In your example, after adding original list, in second sheet select a range like Sheet2!A1:D10.

Step 2: Type =TRANSPOSE(

With those blank cells still selected, type: =TRANSPOSE(

Notice that the A1:D10 cells are still selected even though we have started typing a formula.

Step 3: Type the range of the original cells.

Now type the range of the cells you want to transpose. In your example, as I want to list 10 items, range should be A1:J10. So the formula for this example would be: =TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!A1:J10) -- but don't press ENTER, instead use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, otherwise it won't work.

You can access a definition of transpose formula in office support webpage, just search transpose formula.

Hope it helps.